# Temporal table default constraint for ValidFrom does not work

Tags: sql, date, constraints, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have this specific problem. I am running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (13.0.16000.28) and I want to create temporal table Price. I want to set 'ValidFrom' column to default Value for example '1900-01-01 00:00:00'. Code I am running is

```
CREATE TABLE [DWH_STORE].[dbo].[Price] (
  ID int,
  ProdName nvarchar(40),
  Price int,
  ValidFrom datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START CONSTRAINT DF_ValidFrom DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
  ValidTo datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
          PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ( ValidFrom, ValidTo),
  CONSTRAINT PK_ID_ProdName PRIMARY KEY (ID, ProdName)
) WITH ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[PriceHistory]));
```

However, when I insert Data in my table

```
INSERT INTO [DWH_STORE].[dbo].[Price] (ID, ProdName, Price)
    VALUES (12, 'Banana', 1)`

SELECT * FROM [DWH_STORE].[dbo].[Price]
```

I get

[image: result]

with column 'ValidFrom' as '2017-08-09 11:18:30'. Why I do not get the default value '1900-01-01 00:00:00' for that column as expected?

My Sysdatetime() at the time of insert was '2017-08-09 13:18:30'

I have tried to set DEFAULT as Sysdatetime() to get current date and time, and that does not work either. It seems that If I set DEFAULT to whatever I always get the same result.

I appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got with column 'ValidFrom' as '2017-08-09 11:18:30'. Why I do not get the default value '1900-01-01 00:00:00' for that column as expected?

It is working as expected. Your assumptions are wrong. From [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables):

> INSERTS:
>
> **On an INSERT, the system sets the value for the SysStartTime column to the begin time of the current transaction (in the UTC time zone) based on the system clock and assigns the value for the SysEndTime column to the maximum value of 9999-12-31. This marks the row as open.**

Comment: Okay, thank you. Question is how can I achieve that value of SysStartTime column would have DEFAULT value, for example 'dateadd(dd,(-1),SYSDATETIME ( ))' - yesterday??

Comment: @PeterNagy - if you want to control the datetime values, then you don't want *system-versioned* temporal tables, which is a fuller name for this feature.

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever. If I get this right, this is just because of limitation of _system-versioned_  temporal tables (Regardless, I do not understand why is it possible to set default values for datetime values if they could not be used).

What should I use to control datetime values instead of _system-versioned_ temporal tables? What about using using DEFAULT keyword in INSERT for ValidFrom?

Comment: Maybe the default value for a column does make more sense in the ALTER TABLE case, if there's already data in the table.